# How can I show that $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a countable set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I know that $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a basis on $\mathbb{R}$.

> I need to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is countable.

How can this be done?

---

**Attempt:**

Take $(a,b) \subset \mathcal{B}$, let $\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b) = \{q_1, \ldots, q_n\}$, then $(a,b) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B_\delta(q_i)$ for some $\delta > 0$

But then $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all such $(a,b)$, how do I continue from here?

Comment: I'm not sure you are on the right track. Note that $(a,b)$ is uncountable for any pair of rational numbers $a<b$. You are supposed to show that the number of intervals of this form is countable, which amounts to showing that the number of pairs of rational numbers $(a,b)$ such that $a<b$ is countable.

Comment: If $\mathbb Q$ is countable, then so is $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$. Your collection $\mathcal B$ is indexed by the countable set $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$, so it is a countable collection. It looks like you're confusing the *collection* with the *members of the collection*.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb Q$ is countable, you should also know that $\mathbb Q^2$ is countable.

Comment: $(a,b) \subset \mathcal{B}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: See that $\{\langle a,b\rangle: a,b\in\Bbb Q\land a<b\}\subset\Bbb Q^2$. See [that](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).

Comment: Since OP claims that he knows $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, the question itself has nothing to do with topology.

Comment: It's a matter of indexing.  f:Intervals (a,b) -> order pairs x $\times$ y where y > x via f((a,b)) = a $\times$ b is obviously a bijection.  Q $\times$ Q is countable is pretty basic.  {x $\times$ y | y > x} is coutable.  That y > x is a minor but easy to overcome hiccup.

Comment: The points *within* a single interval (a,b) are not countable so the points within the basis is uncountable.  But that is *not* what is being asked.  What's beings asked is that number of intervals (not the points withing the intervals) is countable.  Each interval is **uniquely** determined by a pair of endpoints.  This endpoints are rational so the number of possible front endpoints is countable.  The number of of possible end endpoints are countable so the crossproduct of pairs of endpoints is countable.  Thus the number of intervals are countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an (obvious) injection $\mathcal{B}\to\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ so that $\mathcal B$ is in bijection with a subset of $\mathbb{Q}\times\Bbb{Q}$, which is countable because $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: I see, so $f: \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}, (a,b) \to \{a\} \times \{b\}$

Answer (score 3):

To show that the set is countable, you need to put all its elements into a list.  Look at how you would do this for $Q$ itself, and (here's a hint) think about how to do this for $Q \times Q$.

Answer (score 2):

For any particular $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, $(a,b)$ is an *element* of $\mathbb{B}$, not a *subset* of $\mathbb{B}$. Thus your attempt is incorrect.

Once you build up a bijection between $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, you can show that $\mathcal{B}$ is countable.